# varying image properties Using MATLAB slider

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

It looks strange, I'm not using slider for viewing image/graph on axes by sliding it. Code shown below is a part of my m-file.

```
function slider2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
fname = getappdata(0, 'fname');
[a, map] = imread(fname);
x = ind2rgb(a, map);
b = get(handles.slider2,'value');
j = imadjust(x,[],[],b);
    axes(handles.axes1);
    imshow(j);
```

`b` in above code is a variable. The moment I slide the slider image brightness changes but at first when I run the code slider's initial point will be in extreme left. But for above code slider should be at the center as shown below

[image: initial]

[image: But I'm expecting this when i run my code]

How can i set values( to increase/decrease brightness) to that slider? How can i go for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use GUIDE: You could set the value within the OpeningFcn

If you are not using GUIDE: You can set the value when creating the slider

assuming, the name (or Tag) of your slider is "slider1":

```
mean_slider = get(handles.slider1,'Max')/2;
set(handles.slider1, 'Value', mean_slider )
```

Comment: I'm using GUIDE, should i use your above codes in opening function?

Comment: if you want to set an initial value for the slider-> yes you should do this within the <my_gui_name>_OpeningFcn(...). Do this BEFORE calling guidata(hObject, handles); !

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example:

```
set(handles.slider2,'value',50)
```

This allows you to set the value of the slider (and make it equal to 50). You can also specify the value of the slider when you create it, using the property inspector if I'm not mistaken.

But the previous line of code doesn't trigger the callback of the slider when executed.